# Azure Cosmos DB ST_DISTANCE function not working with west US coordinates

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using the ST_DISTANCE query which works fine for US east coast coordinates or even in UK etc

but I am getting empty records when moving to US west coast coordinates...

I have verified entries etc Data exist on US west coast as well

are there known bugs with ST_DISTANCE?

```sql
WHERE ST_DISTANCE(c.location, {"type":"Point","coordinates":[34.03183503596681, -118.21750939134851]}) < 500000
```

---

### Update

did a bit more testing works fine from Chicago to India

as soon latitude is -90 or greater it does not work
longitude is -0 or greater it does not work

What's the best way to highlight with the cosmos DB product team?

[roughly following map area works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pbz5.png)

Comment: There are no known bugs with Spatial, and definitely none that only affect a certain region.      Need more information. Can you share sample document, what your partition key is, a complete query and expected results.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The GeoJSON standard uses easting-then-northing for its coordinates.

This means that coordinates are denoted as (longitude, latitude).

You should get the correct answer if you swap the order of your input.

Source: [The GeoJSON Format - RFC7946](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#appendix-A.1)